# Another $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

For the function $x^2$, I was curious if I can prove the limit without the assumption of $|x-a| < 1$, I reached this equation, I don't know if it's right or wrong but I tried a lot of values and I tried to visualize it and it does seem to be true, of course that's not a proof but first how can this equation be wrong?

$$|x-a| < \sqrt{a^2+\epsilon} - |a| $$

and if it's right how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider using MathJax for formatting mathematical expressions. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, what is your assumption about $x$ in your first equation? Obviously, it cannot be true for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I want to proof that for any limit of $x^2$ at a, the limit is $a^2$, the above equation seems to work for any value of a, I'm not sure if it's right, but if it's right I want to prove it

Comment: @SangchulLee I think the idea is to prove (or disprove) that, for $x \in \Bbb{R}$,$$|x - a| < \sqrt{a^2 + \varepsilon} - |a| \implies |x^2 - a^2| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @TheoBendit that's right

Comment: @TheoBendit That makes much more sense. So OP is trying to figure out a sufficient condition that implies $|x^2 - a^2| < \varepsilon$ by not introducing any artificial, auxiliary conditions on $x$.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes exactly

Comment: Well, the implication $$|x - a|<\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}-|a| \quad\implies\quad |x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$$ is always true, and this can be proved by using $$|x^2-a^2|=|(x-a)^2+2a(x-a)|\leq|x-a|^2+2|a||x-a|. $$

Comment: An "equation" is something with an equals sign.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's right, please excuse me it's 4 am here and I'm tired and I can't sleep before I know if this inequality satisfies the epsilon delta definition or not.

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm not quite sure how can I continue this proof

Comment: What Sanchul Lee has demonstrated is the *end* of the proof. The beginning would be to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x - a|< \delta$, then $|x-a| < \sqrt{a^2-\epsilon} - |a|$. The whole concept of this approach seems off. We are talking about the behavior of $x^2$ **as $x$ approaches $a$**. That is what the limit is. But you want to prove it without assuming $|x - a| < 1$. That is, without $x$ having to approach $a$? How does that make sense?